# E2008 Incompatible types

Tags: delphi

В этой части кода выдает ошибку:

```
function TBasicBufferedStream.PeekFor(pb: PByte; len: integer): boolean;
var
  p: dyb.TBytes; //раньше был pointer
begin
  if len < 1 then
    result := true
  else
  begin
    if (fBufFill - fInBufPos) < len then
    begin
      if len > fBufSize then
      begin
        p := fBuf;
        ReallocMem(p, len);
        if p = nil then
          raise EStreamError.Create(Format('can not resize buffer to %d', [len]));
        fBuf := p;
        fBufSize := len;
      end;
      RefillBuffer;
      if fBufFill - fInBufPos < len then
      begin
        result := false;
        exit;
      end;
    end;
    result := CompareMem(@fBuf[fInBufPos], pb, len);
    if result then
      inc(fInBufPos, len);
  end;
end;
```

Все используемые типы

```
fBufSize: longint;
fInBufPos: longint;
fBufFill: Longint;
fBufOffset: int64;
fDirtyStart: integer;
fDirtyEnd: integer;
fPinnedPos: int64;
fBuf: TBytes;
```

Как решить мне эту проблему не пойму!
В Delphi 7 все компилировалось.
Он выдает такую ошибку:

```
[dcc32 Error] bufstream.pas(986): E2008 Incompatible types
```

в строке:

```
ReallocMem(p, len);
```

Comment: обычно компилятор указывает номер строки, где ошибка.

Comment: что такое `dyb.TBytes` и насколько он совместим c `TBytes` ?

Comment: @teran dyb.TBytes и TBytes они совместимы. Ошибку и строку где ошибка добавил.

Comment: ну дак `realloc` наверное указателя требует на вход то?

Comment: Логично. Что-то я сегодня туплю. Решение:  ReallocMem(Pointer(p), len);

Comment: @ValertonGT, если у вас p - это действительно TBytes, то не `ReallocMem()`, а `SetLength(p, len)`, иначе поимеете утечки памяти.